# Python - first word is not being included in search

Tags: python, python-3.6

Why the first word is printing but not included in search in 'dic'.

Can any one tell me the reason and solution how to include first word also?

here is my code:

```
my_dic = {
"a":"1", 
"b":"2", 
"c":"3", 
"d":"4", 
"e":"5", 
}

with open('c:\\english_text_file.txt',encoding = 'utf8') as file :
  for line in file:
    for word in line.split():
      print('word from line.split: ',word)
      if word in my_dic.keys():
       print('word from if word in ...',word)
```

[and the test file is here:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tVk3kpkRGwA85iPiRB8UXTseVmT-GDHLckR1tCxBfEM)

contents of the text file is:

```
a b c d e
```

the output code is:

```
word from line.split:  a
word from line.split:  b
word from if word in ... b
word from line.split:  c
word from if word in ... c
word from line.split:  d
word from if word in ... d
word from line.split:  e
word from if word in ... e
```

Comment: Show your exact output. Put the contents of the text file here. It's not that long. Explain what *you* think is happening.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist both things added in post edits.

Comment: I guess it is something related to saving text file with utf8, because i examine before that when saving a file in utf8, three hidden character and one hidden line is in the beginning of the file. but not sure what exactly going on, you can examine my code using the text file i provided its link in my post.

Comment: UTF-8 is not the issue. Your editor is more likely to be the issue. Is it notepad by any chance?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your problem. Are you sure those are the contents of your file and the encoding is utf8?

Comment: yes! my guess is correct , the clue is , when i saved the same file as ANSI encoding , problem gone and the first word included in search in "my_dic". but i have to save my file as utf-8 because my file contains Urdu language characters also. so please help me.Thanks.

Comment: so after saving as ANSI encoding the output of code is:
word from line.split:  a
word from if word in ... a
word from line.split:  b
word from if word in ... b
word from line.split:  c
word from if word in ... c
word from line.split:  d
word from if word in ... d
word from line.split:  e
word from if word in ... e

Comment: @ Mad Physicist yes i am using notepad.

Comment: @sundance yes the encoding of file which is giving problem is  utf-8, but as i mentioned above , when i changed its encoding from utf-8 to ANSI, the problem was gone, but i need utf-8 for my language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a behavior of windows for txt file: it will add `BOM` to the start of a txt file.

What is `BOM`?

It means `Byte-order mark Description`, value as follows:

```
Byte-order mark Description 
EF BB BF UTF-8 
FF FE UTF-16 aka UCS-2, little endian 
FE FF UTF-16 aka UCS-2, big endian 
00 00 FF FE UTF-32 aka UCS-4, little endian. 
00 00 FE FF UTF-32 aka UCS-4, big-endian.
```

Open your `english_text_file.txt`, and view it with any hex editor you will see the content is:

`efbb bf61 2062 2063 2064 2065 0d0a`

Here, `efbb bf` is the BOM, `61 2062 2063 2064 2065 0d0a` is the ASCII code of `a b c d e\r\n`

So for utf-8 file, we need to check if it has `BOM` at the start, if has, need to remove it.

Next is a sample code for your reference, if you do not mind to change the original file, you can also directly override the old input file, here I just use a new file with no `BOM` in it.

```
import codecs

my_dic = {
    "a":"1",
    "b":"2",
    "c":"3",
    "d":"4",
    "e":"5",
}

content = open('./english_text_file.txt', 'rb').read()
if content[:3] == codecs.BOM_UTF8:
    content = content[3:]
    open('./changed_english_text_file.txt', 'wb').write(content)
else:
    open('./changed_english_text_file.txt', 'wb').write(content)

with open('./changed_english_text_file.txt',encoding = 'utf8') as file :
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            print('word from line.split: ',word)
            if word in my_dic.keys():
                print('word from if word in ...',word)
```

Output is:

```
word from line.split:  a
word from if word in ... a
word from line.split:  b
word from if word in ... b
word from line.split:  c
word from if word in ... c
word from line.split:  d
word from if word in ... d
word from line.split:  e
word from if word in ... e
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your reply, can you please guide me more about which encoding should i chose to avoid this error if i am using Notepad++.
Here are all encoding from Notepad++ encoding Tab:
Encode in ANSI
Encode in UTF-8
Encode in UTF-8-80
Encode in UCS-2 BE BOM
Encode in UCS-2 LE BOM
Character sets 
Convert to ANSI
Convert to UTF-8
Convert to UTF-8-BOM
Convert to UCS-2 BE BOM
Convert to UCS-2 LE BOM

Comment: As I know, this is a behavior of windows default notepad, if your original file was opened and modified by notepad, there will be a BOM added. I use gvim, tried it, no BOM added. I think most modern editor will not do it, including notepad++, could you try it and open with any hex editor to verify it?